# Could this traffic from Amazon AWS traffic be "real" visitors?

Tags: google-analytics, amazon-aws

I have a small blog that occasionally gets featured in a newsletter with world-wide distribution.  When that happens, I see clear spikes in incoming traffic, a significant portion of which is coming from Amazon AWS in Ashburn, Virginia.

Is there a way to determine inside Google Analytics whether these visits are real people?

There are 241 visits from Amazon, 100% new users, 100% bounce rate, 0:00 duration.  Sounds fishy to me.

[image]

Comment: Did you ticked Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders? Under the Google Analytics Admin > View Settings > Bot Filtering If it's known bot then it'll filter out automatically

Comment: I have a view that has bots excluded but it shows zero visits, which is not possible since *I've visited* the site, so it should show at least one visit.  There must be some other incorrect filter in that view which is excluding every visitor, bot or not.  I still think it's interesting that there would be *so many* "unique" visitors from Ashburn.